# Using math package (e.g. math.radians, math.tan) on pandas dataframe column

Tags: pandas, math

Example df:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['1.55', '2.22', '2.22', '3.33'],
                  'col2': ['10', '15', '20', '30']})
```

I want to add a new column using some math functions on `col1`, e.g.

```
data['new'] = math.radians(data['col1'])
```

or

```
data['new'] = math.tan(data['col1'])
```

This gives me the error `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>`. I have converted `col1` to float using `data['col1'] = data['col1'].astype(float64)`, so I think the error must be because `data['new']` cannot be converted to float.

How can I fix this, and use `math` to create new dataframe columns from old ones? An explanation of why `math` isn't playing nice with the dataframe would be great too.

Comment: The problem is not with Pandas. It is just that `math.tan` (and others) expects a number not a list of numbers.

Comment: This may not be appropriate for all functions, but you can convert to float first. `data['new'] = data['col1'].astype(np.float64).map(math.radians)`

Comment: You have to use `Series.apply` here: `data['new'] = data['col1'].astype(float).apply(math.radians)`

Comment: @ako Is that different from doing `data['col1'] = data['col1'].astype(float64)` beforehand?

Comment: no but you need to apply or map the function to each element in the series, per @LoMaPh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways we can solve your problem, since you want to pass scalar values to your math functions:

#### Method 1 using `.astype` and `.apply`:

```
data['new'] = data['col1'].astype(float).apply(math.radians)

   col1 col2       new
0  1.55   10  0.027053
1  2.22   15  0.038746
2  2.22   20  0.038746
3  3.33   30  0.058119
```

#### Method 2 (faster method) is using `numpy` function

*numpy takes arrays as input*

```
data['new2'] = np.tan(data['col1'].astype(float))

   col1 col2       new       new2
0  1.55   10  0.027053  48.078482
1  2.22   15  0.038746  -1.317612
2  2.22   20  0.038746  -1.317612
3  3.33   30  0.058119   0.190669
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't enclose your numerical data frame elements in 'quotation marks'.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1.55, 2.22, 2.22, 3.33],
                     'col2': [10, 15, 20, 30]})
```

If that's just how the data was given to you, use the `.astype` function.

```
data['col1'] = data['col1'].astype(float)
```

When performing an operation on a data frame, use `apply()`.

```
data['new'] = data['col1'].apply(math.tan)
```

Of course this can all be done at once by doing the following code:

```
data['new'] = data['col1'].astype(float).apply(math.tan)
```

Comment: No need for `lambda`, simply use: `data['new'] = data['col1'].apply(math.tan)`. Math.tan is already a function

Comment: You can skip the lambda function.

Comment: Plus the OP's example there are strings. This code would produce an error, see my comment under original question with `astype`

Comment: @Erfan thanks for the tips. I've updated the answer to include your advice.